# What are the differences between "valley", "gorge", "ravine", "canyon", and "gully"?

Tags: word-choice

My Japanese-English dictionary gives `valley`, `gorge`, `ravine`, `canyon`, and `gully` as the translation of Japanese 谷(たに). So far I've only found that `valley` is wide/big, `gorge` and `ravine` are deep and narrow, and that `canyon` is larger and `gully` is smaller than `ravine` and `gorge`. None of my dictionaries gives the difference of `gorge` and `ravine`. What are the differences between these five? Are any of them interchangeable with another in some cases? Thank you.

Comment: In general, a *valley* or *canyon* are created in nature over long periods of time. And I suppose a *canyon* has steeper sides while a *valley* follows the natural terrain and can cover a large area. *gorge* and *ravine* are smaller and can be created in a shorter period of time, such as due to flooding. A *gully* is a very short term, small scale affair. If rain water runs through my yard, it might create a gully in the dirt.

Answer (score 1):

Your definitions are basically correct - any more analysis and you are nitpicking. However, try a Google search to confirm yourself :)

Here is the top image for each word:

[Valley](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Valley#/media/File:Glacier_park1.jpg)

Gorge: [image]

[Ravine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ravine#/media/File:Neatcoulee.jpg)

Canyon: [image]

[Gully](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gully#/media/File:Gully_in_the_Kharkov_region.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

My understanding is a gorge must have a stream running through it.
Ravine is a more general term.  It may or may not have a stream in it.
Thus, a gorge can be called a ravine too, but you can't call a dry ravine a gorge.

Comment: There are many gorges in my part of the world that have no stream in them.  Although they would have been created by a river originally.

Comment: That's not surprising. E.g. if China's 3-Gorges ever becomes dry, the name would not change because in this case, 3-Gorges has become a pronoun, which doesn't have to follow the definition of gorge because a name is just a name.